# ASP.NET app wont share database with Sql Server Management Studio Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005-express, app-data

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 app with a SQL 2005 Express .mdf database file in its App_Data folder. Lets call that Foo.mdf. On its own the ASP.NET app can connect to the database with no problems. So far so good.

Then, if I install [Sql Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796) on the server and start it, it finds the local SQLEXPRESS instance and connects to it, but doesn't show Foo.mdf in the list of databases.

So I try and Attach Foo.mdf by right-clicking on databases and selecting Attach.. and finding the .MDF. This fails with a vague error:

```
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 32(error not found)  
while attempting to open or create the physical file
'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FooApp\App_Data\Foo.mdf'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)
```

If I stop my ASP.NET site in IIS, then the attach *does* work, but then when I restart my ASP.NET app, it can't connect to Foo.mdf.

So it looks like SQL Express 2005 will only let either my app *or* Management Studio connect. This seems really crap - surely Sql Express should allow more than one connection? I was expecting it to behave like regular Sql Server.

Hopefully I'm doing it wrong. Please advise.

Comment: It's not that only one application can connect to the database, it's that only one server can have the database physically attached.  You should attach it to SQL Express and modify your ASP.NET config string to just connect to that server and database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check your application connection string and see if it has **User Instance=true**

eg :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydb.mdf;User Instance=true;
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx) : The other main issue with user instances occurs because SQL Server opens database files with exclusive access. This is necessary because SQL Server manages the locking of the database data in its memory. Thus, if more than one SQL Server instance has the same file open, there is the potential for data corruption. If two different user instances use the same database file, one instance must close the file before the other instance can open it.

If that is the issue, then you can attach the database in SQL Server Management Studio and modify the connection strings as follows so that multiple clients can connect to the same database.

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

If this isnt the issue in your case, also check out the "Common Issues" section at the link above. It could be related to permissions as per points 1 / 2 in the  "Common Issues" section

Comment: I do indeed have `User Instance=True` in my connection string. I'll change it and try out your suggestions. Also that MSDN article points out that I can use SSEUtil to run sql scripts against a user instance, which is the original reason I was looking at SSMSE anyway, so thats handy too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience using the default ASP.NET database, but have you tried moving the MDF to your SQL Express DATA folder? (default: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA) Once in the folder you can use the Management Studio to attach the file to your SQL Express instance. You'll want to modify your connection string in your web.config file to look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following user account to the folder *App_Data* of your website: *SQLServerMSSQLUser$*. Look for it in the advanced security permissions, so you do a search there and then give full control to it.